# How to stop video in background on small devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I have some questions. I have video on website that is playing in header of that website and I want to stop that video on mobile devices (.xs class, I'm using Bootstrap) and instead of that video to show some image in background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found solution. The easiest way to do that is to use media queries. So you just hide your video and show div with image. Simple as that :)